# Synchronous vs Asynchronous socket reads

Tags: performance, sockets, asynchronous, synchronous

Most example apps I come across for receiving data are using async calls. For instance, c++ examples use boost asio services to bind message handlers to callbacks. But what about an app that only needs to listen to data from a single socket and process the messages in order? Would it be faster to have a loop that polls/recv's from the socket and calls the handler without using a callback (assume main and logging threads are separate)? Or is there no performance difference (assume messages are coming in as fast as the network card and kernel can handle them)?

There are many intricacies I don't know such as the impact of callbacks to performance due to things like branch prediction. Or if there will be a performance penalty of the callbacks call a different thread to do the processing. Curious to hear some thoughts, experiences, dialog on this subject to save myself from attempting both implementations to discover the answer.